# Append child not working with newly created element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to append child to a div.

```
<div class="d-flex quantityReceived" id="quantityReceived">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-info changeValue" onclick="allOrderType()"><div id="spinner"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></div></button>
                <input name="order" class="typeahead orderType form-control" type="text" id="allOrderType" aria-describedby="Incomplete Orders" placeholder="Incomplete Orders">
            </div>
```

Here is my javascript to append to the id `quantityReceived`

```
console.log(a)
document.getElementById("quantityReceived").appendChild(a);
```

The element `a` is a combination of elements like this which I can see in the google console.

```
<div id="autocomplete-list" class="auocomplete-items>
  <div>
    "Main"
    <input type="hidden" value="main">
  </div>
  <div>
    "Sub"
    <input type="hidden" value="Sub">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I inspect the parent div with id `quantityReceived`, I do not see the child element a being appended. I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: how you get `a`??

Comment: Seems like you are missing code

Answer (score 0):

The html that you're attempting to append is incorrect.

You need to close the input, so it should look like this:

```
<div id="autocomplete-list" class="auocomplete-items>
  <div>
    "Main"
    <input type="hidden" value="main"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    "Sub"
    <input type="hidden" value="Sub"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then check the result

```
console.log(document.getElementById("quantityReceived"));
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, and just taking a guess since your example is lacking in detail, but I would guess that `a` isn't actually a thing to append correctly. So as a proof of concept to maybe trigger a light bulb to you on your issue;

```js
const child = document.createElement('aside');

document.getElementById('test1').appendChild(child);
```

```css
div {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border: red 1px dashed;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

div aside {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: green 3px dotted;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that your HTML-to-be-appended is invalid, I think it should not be a problem (if indeed that HTML is a DOM node and not a string!), see:

```js
let a = document.createElement('div');
a.setAttribute('class', 'autocomplete-items');
a.setAttribute('id', 'autocomplete-list');
a.innerHTML = `
  <div>
    Main
    <input type="hidden" value="main" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Sub
    <input type="hidden" value="sub" />
  </div>
`;


document.getElementById("quantityReceived").appendChild(a);
```

```html
<div class="d-flex quantityReceived" id="quantityReceived">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info changeValue" onclick="allOrderType()">
    <div id="spinner">
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
  </button>

  <input name="order" class="typeahead orderType form-control" type="text" id="allOrderType" aria-describedby="Incomplete Orders" placeholder="Incomplete Orders" />
</div>
```